# drawImage(HTML5CanvasElement) Firefox Memory Exponential Increase

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

I'm trying to use JavaScript drawImage to draw from a buffer canvas to another in Firefox; I'm calling the draw multiple times per frame using a fairly large canvas. My memory usage shoots through the roof in Firefox, but barely peaks in Chrome. I'm curious about the reason for this behavior and if there's a workaround to free the memory used (I'm assuming) by drawn images after they're no longer needed.

I need to render using globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in', so that's why I'm using this method.

Here's the basic idea:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
//set height and width of canvas to browser window

var dummyCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var dummyctx = dummyCanvas.getContext('2d');
dummyCanvas.width = canvas.width;
dummyCanvas.height = canvas.height;

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    //draw some stuff on normal canvas

    dummyCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    //draw a polygon on buffer canvas
    dummyctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
    //draw another polygon on buffer canvas

    ctx.drawImage(dummyctx.canvas, 0, 0);

    //draw some more stuff on normal canvas
}
```

Is this memory problem just a bug in Firefox? Am I doing something wrong? Are there any workarounds?

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution ? I'm facing exactly the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I notixed that images are somehow piled on each other in a canvas, when I dra more than one. Maybe it would help clearing te canvas, before draing to it again:

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var w = canvas.width;
canvas.width = 1;
canvas.width = w;
```

I took this from a image resize that I dod not so long ago: http://boxed.hu/articles/html5-client-side-image-resize/

But, this is only a tip - so let me know how it worked.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm actually clearing the canvas every frame, as part of the normal run-loop of the program; so they wouldn't be stacking.

Answer (score 0):

I had a memory leak problem with the [jquery.rotate](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) plugin increasing the memory use on IE and found that although drawing takes up memory, the problem was when the original image was replaced by the manipulated image. Apparently the images were just piling up in memory. The line was:

```
p.parentNode.replaceChild(canvas, p);
```

so I changed to use the jQuery function replaceWith() and the memory stopped stacking up after rotating several images:

```
$(p).replaceWith(canvas);
```

Looking at the replaceWith function, it actually removes the object (probably in the end uses removeChild and appendChild) and appends the new one to the DOM. My guess is that there's a difference on how the browsers implement replaceChild().